# jQuery Ajax Response give me my index.html

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I'm running my jQuery Ajax request, my data is my own index.html

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {  
            'GET': '/to/yourls-api.php?username=api&password=short&action=shorturl&url=facebook.com&keyword=facebook&format=json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'contentType': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
    }
```

How to solve this? 
I tried `function(result)` also, but got the same response.

Comment: We need to know your server side code. You are probably doing something wrong there. What is the result you expect?

Comment: If you are expecting html you shouldn't have the headers datatype as json

Comment: Also sending passwords in the URL is considered a bad practice in most situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not building correctly the ajax call. It must be like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/to/yourls-api.php?username=api&password=short&action=shorturl&url=facebook.com&keyword=facebook&format=json',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
    }
```

If this doesn't work I would also like to see the HTTP request and response from developer tools of the browser that you are using (F12 in Chrome).

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json',` is nonsense, it's a GET request, there is no content to describe the type of.